# extract word using regular expression in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

Here is my string

```
var str = 'varying<div class="desc_1"><div>Changing or xyz</div></div>';
```

And I want to extract "varying" and "Changing or xyz" word from sentence using **regular expression** in javascript. I want output like this

```
str1 = "varying";
str2 = "Changing or xyz";
```

[Js Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/11049670/1/)

Comment: Are you trying to parse html code? If not you are better off creating separate text nodes and `div` nodes, then make changes to you text nodes when needed.

Comment: i want to store this two separate string in json

Comment: You could try `str.split(/<[^>]+>/).filter(function( txt ){ return txt != "" })` but seriously, don't use regular expressions to parse HTML.

Comment: Ohhk. Thanks. I'll use create element method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you *need* to use a regular expression here?

```js
var str = 'varying<div class="desc_1"><div>Changing or xyz</div></div>';
var tmp = document.createElement('div');
tmp.innerHTML = '<div>' + str + '</div>';

var text = [];

var divs = tmp.getElementsByTagName('div');
for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
  var textEle = divs[i].childNodes[0];
  if (textEle.nodeValue !== null) {
    text.push(textEle.nodeValue);
  }
}

console.log(text);
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = text.join(', ');
```

```html
<p id="output"></p>
```